# Existe algum framework para android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de encontrar um *framework* para Android parecido com **Bootstrap** utilizado no *layout* de paginas web, existe algum? Qual o mais indicado?

Comment: Pesquise por Google Material Design

Comment: Vai depender da versão, na versões mais recentes Android 5.0 (API level 21), isso já é nativo https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Comment: Ok pessoal, Obrigado!